# starting selenium server command is blocking my python code execution

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I want to launch selenium server command with python (`subprocess.popen`)  and then I want to execute some other commands on that server:

```
subprocess.popen(selenium Server command)

subprocess.popen(next command which should be launched while command selenium server is launched)
```

the problem is that the first command won't terminate unless the second one is terminated , and since the second is never launched as python is waiting for the first to terminate my code blocks

should I work with multithreading to make that work or is there an other solution ? and how can I do that since I never used multi threading before ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start your first command in the background.  Then you can interact with it in your program, or start another client to do the interaction.

(This assumes Linux)

```
import subprocess, time

procs = []
procs.append( subprocess.Popen(
    'sleep 3 ; echo first &',
    shell=True) )

procs.append( subprocess.Popen(
    '/bin/echo beer',
    shell=True) )

print '\nwaiting for workers:'
for proc in procs:
    print proc.communicate()
```

Sample output.  Notice that `beer` comes before `first` -- the first shell command waited for three seconds before doing its output.

```
waiting for workers:
beer
first
(None, None)
(None, None)
```